# Strange FloatingActionButton tint behaivior

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to give my FloatingActionButton a background color different than that defined as accentColor in my style. So far I try to do this:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/primaryColor"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24" />
```

Where this is inside a CoordinatorLayout. This is what i get:

[image]

As you can see there is a blue circle around the fab. I don't know how to get rid of it. I also tried to define a style for this fab, but then i got black and it messed up completely. I think it could have to do something with its shadow, but I also don't know how to change it without changing elevation.

Comment: Use app:backgroundTint

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit more trying out I got the solution:

You just need to add `app:borderWidth="0dp"` and it's gone.

Other way to do it is to use `app:backgroundTint=""`.

Answer (score 0):

Pleas Try this code its use full

```
 <com.rey.material.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/user_add_item_to_card"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    app:fab_iconSrc="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:background="#FFF">
</com.rey.material.widget.FloatingActionButton>
```

Comment: I don't see the need to include an other library in my app